# publish red5 web project in linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, red5

I have created a dynamic web project  in eclipse and published it via red5-eclipse plugin in Windows.
I need to publish the same application in red 5 server installed in Linux machine.
In case of Windows just copying the application folder under webapps and restarting the red5 server works.
But when i try the same in Linux its not working.
Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Even on windows you shouldn't be doing the work of copy/paste into the webapps folder.
Thats the very reason to use the Red5 plugin in eclipse, i.e to make your life easier.

I assume you are using the JAVA EE version of eclipse. Just follow this old tutorial, which is still very much valid:
http://trac.red5.org/wiki/Red5Plugin

Once configured properly, you will see the Red5 Server in the bottom panel under the "Servers" tab. There you can directly publish your app to the server, debug, start/stop etc.

For your Linux specific issue, in most probability, you have to set the correct permissions for the Red5 webapps directory in order to put new projects in there. There is no reason otherwise for it to work differently than Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Using Netbeans and Glassfish Server:

Red5 can be installed as stand alone server or as a war deployment.

The procedure is to create war deployment of red5 version 0.8(old version). (Lengthy, please bear with me).

Download and install jdk1.6, glassfish2.1 and netbeans 6.5 on linux.

Download "Red5War_0.8.0.war".

I am sharing in the hope that the following may help the community to create a deployable war red5 version 0.8 on glassfish2.1 by following the steps using in Netbeans 6.5:

Step 1: Un-zip the Red5War_0.8.0.war

Step 2: Create a web project named "red5" in Netbeans

Step 3: Copy the content of "/WEB-INF/classes" of inflated war folder and paste it in "Source Packages" of Netbeans Project.

Step 4: Right Click "Libraries", add "JAR/Folder", navigate to "/WEB-INF/lib" of inflated war folder, select all the dependency jars and Click On "Open" of Netbeans Project.

Step 5: Delete WEB-INF of Netbeans Project (Note : Ignore Warning/Error).

Step 6: Delete META-INF of the inflated folder.

Step 7: Copy the remaining content ("/WEB-INF/classes" and "/WEB-INF/lib") of the inflated folder to "Web Pages" of Netbeans Project.

Step 8: Open the following ports in the firewall TCP/843,TCP/1935,TCP/5229,TCP/5080

Step 9: Run the project

Step 10: Deployable war file "red.war" is created in the Netbeans Project Folder(../NetBeansProjects/red5/dist/)

Please share your findings in creating new version(1.0, 1.0.1, 1.02) war deployments using new version netbeans, jdk on new version glassfish server(3.x).

Best wishes!

Arumugam A.V